# ListView reads the file, but WebView won't display it

Tags: android, listview, webview

I am using ListView to list all the pictures in the folder, then in onListItemClick I start another activity, pass the name to it and display the picture in the webview in the next activity. Even though the picture is in the folder and the ListView reads it correctly, the WebView won't display it, any thought ?

Here's my code:

```
public class Dives extends ListActivity {

private File currentDir;

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
     currentDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "DivePlanner" + File.separator);

     FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return (name.endsWith("png") || name.endsWith("jpg") || name.endsWith("jpeg") || name.endsWith("PNG") || name.endsWith("JPG") || name.endsWith("JPEG"));
            }
        };

    String[] values = currentDir.list(filter);
     if (values == null) 
        {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", 500).show();
        } 

     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
     setListAdapter(adapter);
     getListView().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.diver));
}

@Override

protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View v, int position, long id) {
    list.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.diver));
    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, DisplayDive.class);

    Bundle B = new Bundle();
    B.putString("jmeno", item);
    myIntent.putExtras(B);

    this.startActivity(myIntent);


}
```

}

Which displays the files and in OnClick starts another activity which displays the file:

```
public class DisplayDive extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
WebView myWebView;
String jmeno;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.table);
    Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras!=null) jmeno = extras.getString("jmeno");

    myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    myWebView.setInitialScale(100);
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ File.separator + "DivePlanner" + File.separator + jmeno);

}
```

}

The WebView always ends up with page not available /mnt/sdcard/DivePlanner/file_name.jpeg

one more thing: I don't really understand why is the folder in the phone memory, shouldn't it be on the SDcard ? (I export some pngs from my app to this folder, to my surprise, the folder wasn't created on the SD card but on the phone instead)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to append the scheme for the Webview to show it.

```
file:///mnt/sdcard/Dive.....
```

What made you conclude that the file is on the phone?